# Azure Eventhub Sequence Number sequencing

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I know the below is true for sequence number within a partition :-

Sequence Number follows a predictable pattern where numbering is contiguous and unique within the scope of a partition. So if message x has sequence number 500 , message y will have sequence number 501.

Say last sequence number when message was received was 5000, and then no more messages were received and after 7 days retention policy , on 10th day we receive a message on the partition , will the sequence number start from 5001 or will it be different this time?

The reason i am asking because I am seeing:
"The expected sequence number xxx is less than the received sequence number yyy."?

For example:-
The supplied sequence number '33508' is invalid. The last sequence number in the system is '583'

Comment: what is the package you are suing?

Comment: The package is irrelevant in this case;  sequencing is a responsibility of the Event Hubs service, not the SDK.

Comment: Generally speaking, the sequence numbers for a partition are contiguous.   That said, I'm not sure of the service behavior if all events have aged out and a partition is empty.  I've reflected this question to a member of the Event Hubs service team.   One of us will follow-up here when an answer is available.

Comment: Can you check the creation time of the eventhub? Let's make sure it is not recreated at some point.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca:  Just to double-check, does that imply confirmation that the expected service behavior should be to start sequencing contiguous to the last event, even if everything aged out of the partition?

Comment: @JesseSquire Sequence number is always contiguous. It can only be interrupted by recreating the eventhub.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca, does  adding a new topic to the eventhub also falls into "recreating the eventhub."?

Comment: @Prerna, no. Adding a new topic under the same namespace won't affect existing ones. The scenario here is deleting an eventhub and recreating it back.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca, thanks , so in this case event hub wasn’t recreated.

Comment: Did the senders stop for 7 days? What was the reason for no-receive?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca,It’s on staging environment, So when needed messages are sent to event hub for testing , so if there is a gap of more then 7 days we are observing this.

Comment: This now started to sound like a service side issue. Will you be able to open a support ticket so we can investigate it further?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca, can you please help me how to create a support ticket , provide a link to do the same.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca, i created a support ticket :- 2106080040005360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update this post with answer, we found the concerned EventHubs are indeed recreated, but checkpoint store was not reset. Thus, SequenceNumber presented by client (read from checkpoint store) was greater than latest sequence number at service.

As Serkant confirmed above, Sequence number is always contiguous. It can only be interrupted by recreating the eventhub. Typically, you shouldn’t have a need to delete and recreate EventHub in production. But in case you run into the situation, you should also reset checkpoint store.

HTH,
Amit Bhatia